# The state of my checkboxes keep returning to their original value in flutter

Tags: flutter, forms, web, flutter-web, state-management

I have a profile page with some widgets which after saving and redrawing, they keep their new states, but my checkboxes do not, and I have not modified them at all. The new value is being saved on the database, but on the UI it's not preserved. If I turn the email checkbox to true, the 'true' boolean is saved, but it's not displayed on the frontend after pressing the submit button.

```
class _ProfilePageState extends State<ProfilePage> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  bool? emailIsChecked = false;
  bool? smsisChecked = false;
  bool isTextFieldEnabled = false;
  bool isIgnored = true;
  bool isVisible = false;
  bool editIsVisible = true;
  bool emailIsEnabled = false;
  bool smsIsEnabled = false;
  bool nameEdit = false;


  late TextEditingController countryController;
  late TextEditingController languageController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    countryController = TextEditingController(text: globals.signedInUser!.country);
    languageController = TextEditingController(text: globals.signedInUser!.language);

    selectedCountry = globals.signedInUser!.country;
    selectedLanguage = globals.signedInUser!.language;

    globals.signedInUser!.notifications.forEach(
      (element) {
        if ((element['type']) == 'Email') {
          emailIsChecked = element['status'];
        }
        if ((element['type']) == 'SMS') {
          smsisChecked = element['status'];
        }
      },
    );
    cleanInputStates();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {

    countryController.dispose();
    languageController.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  checkEditVisibility() {
    if (editIsVisible == true) {
      return true;
    }
    if (editIsVisible == false) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  checkEditAvailability() {
    if (editIsVisible == false) {
      return true;
    }
    if (editIsVisible == true) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  cleanInputStates() {
    isTextFieldEnabled = false;
    isIgnored = true;
    editIsVisible = true;
    isVisible = false;
    smsIsEnabled = false;
    emailIsEnabled = false;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Flexible(
              flex: 5,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 30,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Visibility(
                          visible: editIsVisible,
                          maintainSize: true,
                          maintainAnimation: true,
                          maintainState: true,
                          child: ElevatedButton.icon(
                              style: ButtonStyle(
                                  backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.green)),
                              icon: const Icon(Icons.edit),
                              label: Text('Edit'),
                              onPressed: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  isTextFieldEnabled = true;
                                  isIgnored = false;
                                  isVisible = true;
                                  editIsVisible = false;
                                  smsIsEnabled = true;
                                  emailIsEnabled = true;
                                });
                              }),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 250,
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 30,
                    ),
                    Flexible(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 20,
                                ),
                                ... // TextFieldInputs
                                Row(
                                  children: [
                                    Container(
                                      child: Text(
                                        "Country: ",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          fontSize: 22,
                                          color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 100,
                                    ),

                                    Container(
                                      width: 300,
                                      child: IgnorePointer(
                                        ignoring: isIgnored,
                                        child: DropdownButtonFormField2(
                                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                                            isDense: true,
                                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          isExpanded: true,
                                          hint: const Text(
                                            'Select Your Country',
                                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                                          ),
                                          icon: const Icon(
                                            Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                                            color: Colors.black45,
                                          ),
                                          iconSize: 30,
                                          buttonHeight: 60,
                                          buttonPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 10),
                                          dropdownDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                                          ),
                                          items: countryItems
                                              .map((item) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                                    value: item,
                                                    child: Text(
                                                      item,
                                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                                        fontSize: 14,
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                  ))
                                              .toList(),
                                          validator: (valueCountry) {
                                            if (valueCountry == null) {
                                              return 'Please select country.';
                                            }
                                            return null;
                                          },
                                          value: selectedCountry,
                                          onChanged: (String? valueCountry) {
                                            selectedCountry = valueCountry;
                                            setState(() {
                                              valueCountry;
                                            });
                                          },
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    // ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 20,
                                ),
                                Row(
                                  children: [
                                    Container(
                                      child: Text(
                                        "Language: ",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          fontSize: 22,
                                          color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 80,
                                    ),

                                    Container(
                                      width: 300,
                                      child: IgnorePointer(
                                        ignoring: isIgnored,
                                        child: DropdownButtonFormField2(
                                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                                            isDense: true,
                                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          isExpanded: true,
                                          hint: const Text(
                                            'Select Your Language',
                                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                                          ),
                                          icon: const Icon(
                                            Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                                            color: Colors.black45,
                                          ),
                                          iconSize: 30,
                                          buttonHeight: 60,
                                          buttonPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 10),
                                          dropdownDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                                          ),
                                          items: languageItems
                                              .map((item) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                                    value: item,
                                                    child: Text(
                                                      item,
                                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                                        fontSize: 14,
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                  ))
                                              .toList(),
                                          value: selectedLanguage,
                                          validator: (valueLanguage) {
                                            if (valueLanguage == null) {
                                              return 'Please select language.';
                                            }
                                            return null;
                                          },
                                          onChanged: (String? valueLanguage) {
                                            selectedLanguage = valueLanguage;
                                            setState(() {
                                              valueLanguage;
                                            });
                                          },
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    // ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                Row()
                              ],
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 120,
                            ),
                            Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Row(
                                  children: [
                                    Container(
                                      child: Row(
                                        children: [
                                          Text(
                                            "Receive notifications by: ",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              fontSize: 22,
                                              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 10,
                                ),
                                Row(
                                  children: [
                                    Container(
                                      width: 300,
                                      child: CheckboxListTile(
                                        enabled: emailIsEnabled,
                                        title: Text("E-mail"),
                                        value: emailIsChecked,
                                        onChanged: (bool? newEmailValue) {
                                          setState(() {
                                            emailIsChecked = newEmailValue;
                                          });
                                        },
                                        activeColor: Colors.green,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                Row(
                                  children: [
                                    Container(
                                      width: 300,
                                      child: CheckboxListTile(
                                        enabled: smsIsEnabled,
                                        title: Text("SMS"),
                                        value: smsisChecked,
                                        onChanged: (bool? newSmsValue) {
                                          setState(() {
                                            smsisChecked = newSmsValue;
                                          });
                                        },
                                        activeColor: Colors.green,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 100,
                                ),
                                Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Visibility(
                                      visible: isVisible,
                                      child: Row(
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          ElevatedButton(
                                            style: ButtonStyle(
                                                backgroundColor:
                                                    MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.red)),
                                            onPressed: () {
                                              setState(() {
                                                cleanInputStates();
                                                _formKey.currentState!.reset();
                                                Navigator.push(
                                                    context,
                                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                                        builder: (context) => ProfilePage()));
                                              });
                                              print("Cleaning states");
                                            },
                                            child: Text("Dismiss"),
                                          ),
                                          SizedBox(
                                            width: 100,
                                          ),
                                          ElevatedButton(
                                            style: ButtonStyle(
                                                backgroundColor:
                                                    MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.green)),
                                            onPressed: () {
                                              if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                                                final userInfo = {
                                                  "_id": globals.signedInUser!.userId,
                                                  "firstName": firstnameTextController.text,
                                                  "lastName": lastnameTextController.text,
                                                  "email": emailTextController.text,
                                                  "phoneNumber": phoneNumberTextController.text,
                                                  "country": selectedCountry.toString(),
                                                  "language": selectedLanguage.toString(),
                                                  "notifications": [
                                                    {"type": "Email", "status": emailIsChecked},
                                                    {"type": "SMS", "status": smsisChecked}
                                                  ]
                                                };
                                                globals.socketController.updateUser(userInfo);
                                                Fluttertoast.showToast(
                                                  msg: "Applying changes.", // message
                                                  toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG, // length
                                                  gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM_RIGHT, // location
                                                  timeInSecForIosWeb: 2,
                                                  webBgColor: "#4caf50",
                                                );
                                              }
                                              print("DATA IS BEING SAVED");
                                              setState(() {
                                                if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                                                  globals.signedInUser!.email =
                                                      emailTextController.text;
                                                  globals.signedInUser!.phoneNumber =
                                                      phoneNumberTextController.text;
                                                  globals.signedInUser!.firstName =
                                                      firstnameTextController.text;
                                                  globals.signedInUser!.lastName =
                                                      lastnameTextController.text;
                                                  globals.signedInUser!.country =
                                                      selectedCountry as String;
                                                  globals.signedInUser!.language =
                                                      selectedLanguage as String;
                                                  
                                                

                                                  cleanInputStates();
                                                  Navigator.push(
                                                      context,
                                                      MaterialPageRoute(
                                                          builder: (context) => ProfilePage()));
                                                } else {
                                                  print("ingresando else");
                                                }
                                              });
                                            },
                                            child: Text("Save"),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ), //Column ends here
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: the culprit on your problem is the  cleanInputStates(); . Try to comment it , and see if it will solve the problem. or move it after  super.initState();

Comment: @Paulo the cleanInputStates(); method within the submit button or the method itself that is after the dispose?

Comment: I commented  the cleanInputStates(); within the superInit and partially solve the issue. Now what happens is that if I change to another page and go back into the profile page, the value of the checkboxes return to the previous state and the changes are not being kept.

Answer (score 0):

Update: After some testings and workarounds, I found that the second issue was due to not assigning a new value prior to returning to the initState. To do that, I added the following code segment into the setState() of the submit button, which is the fetch of the notification parameters within the initState() but assigning the new checkbox values into the array. Additionally, I removed the cleanInputStates(); on the initState as @Paulo mentioned and everything else kept the same.

```
globals.signedInUser!.notifications.forEach(
      (element) {
        if ((element['type']) == 'Email') {
           element['status'] = emailIsChecked;
        }
        if ((element['type']) == 'SMS') {
           element['status'] = smsisChecked;
        }
      },
    );
```